# Resident Memory increases with Lucene Mmap

Tags: java, lucene, mmap

Currently i'm Mmap 1.5 GB of lucene index, i noticed virtual memory size gone up from 14GB to 23GB(that's fine this size includes the size of swapout pages in hard-drive). But i'm witnessing increase in RSS(resident-size) size from 8GB to 12GB if we use MMAP. Any suggestion to reduce RSS usage without compensating performance.

Regards,
Raghavan

Answer (score 0):

[Mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) allows Lucene to work directly on page cache ( by loading the Lucene index on page cache and avoiding copying the page cache to bytes on heap so this should not lead to increase in resident memory. For an excellent and must read check [here](https://blog.thetaphi.de/2012/07/use-lucenes-mmapdirectory-on-64bit.html)) .You might want to  take a heap dump to ascertain if the increase in resident size is not due to any heap objects.

Comment: What we are noticing was our average resident memory consumption by the process is more compared to free memory usage in RAM.